# delegate from VC to TableViewCell to update cell

Tags: swift, delegates, tableview, cell

I'm trying to update all my cell from my VC with delegate.

it works from cell to update something on VC, but when I try to update something from VC to make changes on cell, it doesn't work.

In my VC I added :

```
protocol MainViewDelegate {
    func updateValueInCell()
}
```

```
var delegate: MainViewDelegate?
```

```
@IBAction func modifyValueAtVC(_ sender: Any) {
    func updateValueInCell()
}
```

and in my cell

```
var mainView = ViewController()
```

```
extension CustomTableViewCell : MainViewDelegate {
    func updateValueInCell() {
        print("hello")
    }
```

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        mainView.delegate = self
    }
```

but nothing happened when I pressed my button from my View Controller.

is it the correct way on update cell from VC or do you guys have any other ideas?

thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vc update cell only need reloadData, if u want cell trigger viewcontroller by cell, use delegate.

```
class MainView:UIViewController,CustomTableViewCellDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!//table.delegate = self
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DailyScheduleTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        //update what you want
        return cell
    }

    func onClick(cell: CustomTableViewCell) {
        //cell click trigger
    }

    @IBAction func modifyValueAtVC(_ sender: Any) {
        table.reloadData()
    }
}

protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate{
    func onClick(cell:CustomTableViewCell)
}

class CustomTableViewCell:UITableViewCell{
    var delegate:CustomTableViewCellDelegate!

    @IBAction func onClick(_ sender: Any) {
        del?.onClick(cell: self)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yes, it works that way, but what if the condition is flipped? like, the action is from VC and update something on cell??

Comment: u call reloadData and update cell in  MainView's cellForRowAt